# Best way to migrate from MySQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, migration

I have to migrate a MySQL database to PostgreSQL. I have tried the mysqldump with --compatible = postresql. I have seen that some poeple use ETL like Talend to make the migration but you must describe the migration for all tables... (I have 39 tables...)

Any other idea ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: My team is using Talend.  I know it's a good option but I don't think its free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the tables by hand, and then script the data inserts with Perl/PHP/Python/etc, and just run through the data, preferably using PDO (to get around Pg's issues with BLOB data).

Comment: Probably the easiest way if `mysqldump` wasn't able to produce anything usable.  Leave out all indexes and constraints until AFTER you load your data to make life easier: You won't have to unwind the dependencies & you'll save lots of time if you're not updating indexes on every insert.

Comment: Nothing automatic ???

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Talend.

This [Video](https://youtu.be/dqja5wZRq0k) describes at first how to do use a dynamic scheme for one table, then how to expand to doing a whole database dynamically.

Below is a screen capture of such a job. It connects to the database, grabs the list of tables from a database, and then iterates through those tables.

[image: Job for migrating a database.]

The trick is selecting a dynamic schema for the tables, as seen below.

[image: dynamic table schema]

Ps: I work for Talend.

Comment: Welcome to SO! We typically ask that answers be self-contained in case their links go dead or are otherwise unavailable. Can you bring in some of the key points from the video here?

Comment: @ceejayoz added some screen captures based on your reply.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Migration from MySQL to PostgreSQL can be automated with tools like [Ispirer Toolkit](https://www.ispirer.com/products/migration-toolkit).